# Building Gktmm 3.91 from source using gcc 7

Tags: c++17, autoconf, gtkmm3, gcc7

OS : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Compiler : Gcc7.2

I want to add Gtkmm3.9 as a third party dependency for one of my project and I try to compile from the source. I'm not familiar with autoconf or automake toolset.

Going through the documentation https://developer.gnome.org/anjuta-build-tutorial/stable/create-autotools.html.en I've found that you can autogen.sh to generate configure file. But the project is not able to configure and hence cannot generate any make files too.

```
Gtkmm/gtkmm-3.91.2$ sh autogen.sh 
autogen.sh: 5: autogen.sh: mm-common-prepare: not found
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force --warnings=all -I build 
${ACLOCAL_FLAGS}
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'build'.
libtoolize: copying file 'build/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'build'.
libtoolize: copying file 'build/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'build/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'build/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'build/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'build/lt~obsolete.m4'
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force --warnings=all
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force --warnings=all
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing --
warnings=all
configure.ac:51: installing 'build/compile'
configure.ac:51: installing 'build/config.guess'
configure.ac:51: installing 'build/config.sub'
configure.ac:28: installing 'build/install-sh'
configure.ac:28: installing 'build/missing'
Makefile.am:26: error: ENABLE_DOCUMENTATION does not appear in 
AM_CONDITIONAL
automake: error: cannot open < build/dist-changelog.am: No such file  or directory
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
./configure: line 3211: syntax error near unexpected token `0.9.10'
./configure: line 3211: `MM_PREREQ(0.9.10)'
```

I want to use C++17 and it seems modern C++ is supported after Gtkmm 3.81 as a parallel build to already existing Gtk3. I cannot find any ubuntu prebuilt packages for Gtkmm3.81.

- Does the Gtkmm3.9 repository contains all the dependencies within its repository.
- Can that be used with C++17 (I use gcc7.2 compiler)
  I cannot compile any programs with old Gtkmm3 with C++17 as there are some removed functions in the header.

I intend to use the library with C++17. More interested in the building the library ourselves.Any build instructions would be very helpful too.

Thanks  Johny